# NodeJS with Angular2, using debugable Typescript on server and client

Tags: node.js, angular, debugging, typescript, visual-studio-code

Anybody know of a configured template, using NodeJS on the serverside and Angular on the client side? Both written in transpiled Typescript. Both should be debugable.

The IDE is not important, but would be great if working with VS Code.

Often, when finding boilerplate for this, it is only one or the other - I have not seen a Typescript server and client setup with Angular.

Comment: what you are looking for is boilerplate code, there plenty templates on GitHub, or give yeoman a try.  you can get anything working on any ide.

Comment: Thanks - do you have a specific recommendation for this setup?

Comment: This uses express and angular with typescript: https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-starter